# How to knit pdf from rmd script by clicking an executable r file?

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

**Synopsis**

I would like to produce a pdf file from an rmd script just by clicking a file / an icon so that my coworkers don't exhaust themselves by opening RStudio first.

**The question**

When I saw [this](http://www.r-bloggers.com/making-r-files-executable-under-windows/) on R-bloggers, and got it working, I thought I was approaching the perfect work flow from scripting to sharing my work by letting my coworkers execute a file and get a pdf with updated numbers as a result. However, I can't get it to work with some of the functions in the knitr library.

Best case scenario is that this question is interesting to only a few of you out there, but here goes:

Below you can see a script in a file called **RexecKnit.Rmd**.
The only reason it's there is so you can test the whole procedure for yourselves if you want to. By the way, I'm running RStudio Version 0.99.467 on Windows 7, 64 bit.

````
---
title: "Executable R, rmd and pdf"
header-includes: \usepackage{caption} \usepackage{fancyhdr}
output: pdf_document
fig_caption: no
---

\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5cm} 
\pagestyle{fancyplain} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

```{r Settings, echo = FALSE, eval = TRUE, results = "hide", warning = FALSE, message = FALSE}
rm(list=ls())

pck_loaded <- (.packages())

# Packages to load
pck_toload <- c('ggplot2', 'xts', 'quantmod', 'zoo', 'PerformanceAnalytics',
            'tseries', 'mvtnorm', 'data.table', 'XLConnect', 'sqldf', 'stargazer', 'xtable', 'gridExtra', 'grid', 'TTR')

# Load packages
for(i in 1:length(pck_toload)) {
   if (!pck_toload[i] %in% pck_loaded)
    print(pck_toload[i])
    library(pck_toload[i], character.only = TRUE)
}

```

\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=empty}

```{r repex1, echo = FALSE, eval = TRUE, results = "asis", warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, fig.width = 12, fig.height = 8}

# Data table with formatted numbers and text
v1 <- c("\\colorbox{white}{0.05}" , "\\colorbox{yellow}{0.57}", "\\colorbox{red}{-0.99}")
v2 <- c("An unexpected comment", "A qurious question", "And an insightful answer")
dt1 <- data.table(v1,v2)

# Data table using xtable
print(xtable(dt1,
      caption = 'Fancy table'),
      caption.placement = 'top',
      comment = FALSE,
      sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)
```

```{r repex2, echo = FALSE, eval = TRUE, results = "asis", warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, fig.width = 12, fig.height = 8}

# Data table wiht random numbers
dt2 <- data.table(replicate(2,sample(0:100,10,rep=TRUE)))

# ggplot of random numbers
plx <- ggplot(data=dt2 ,aes(x=V1, y = V2))
plx <- plx + geom_line(color = 'blue', fill = 'grey')
plx <- plx + theme_classic()
plx <- plx + labs(title="Random numbers", x="x-axis",y="y-axis")
plot(plx)
```
````

I know that's a pretty lengthy script for testing purposes, but it's just to make sure that everything works when I execute the script upon double clicking this little beauty [image: .Rexe] which is a file called **caller knitr.Rexe** (like in the R-Bloggers post) containing this little piece of code:

```
library(knitr)
library(rmarkdown)
setwd('C:/repos/r_tutorials/executable R files')
knit('RexecKnit.Rmd')
Sys.sleep(3)
```

And this works as expected. Upon double klicking the file, the script is run without opening R or Rstudio, and a .md file is produced in the desired folder. And the same script works when it's stored as a .Rexe file and as a .R file.
But here's the problem:

I want to produce a pdf, and according to a tip [here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/), replacing

```
knit('RexecKnit.Rmd')
```

with

```
rmarkdown::render("RexecKnit.Rmd")
```

should do the trick as long as the YAML header includes this:

```
output: pdf_document
```

And it does work (meaning that the pdf is created with every detail specified in the lenghty script), at least when it is run as an .R file.
To my disappointment, it does NOT work when it is run from a .Rexec file like this:

```
library(knitr)
library(rmarkdown)
setwd('C:/repos/r_tutorials/executable R files')
rmarkdown::render("RexecKnit.Rmd")
Sys.sleep(3)
```

Thank you for having a look at this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming one has independently installed `pandoc` on `Windows` machine (*which turned out to be the root of the problem in this case*), she can do it in the following manner:

**First**: make a `.R` file with the content like below

```
library(knitr)
library(rmarkdown)
setwd('C:/repos/r_tutorials/executable R files')
knit("RexecKnit.Rmd")

# render the generated markdown file.
render("RexecKnit.md")

Sys.sleep(3)
```

**Second**: make a `.bat` file

Create a .bat file, say "my_bat_file.bat", and include the text below. However, the paths have to be adjusted:

```
"C:\R\R-3.2.2\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD BATCH --vanilla --slave "C:\path_to_your_file\your_file.R" "C:\path_to_your_file\your_file.Rout"
```

**Third**: Instruct `Windows Task Scheduler`

If the data is updated frequently, one can shedule the Task Scheduler in Windows to repeatedly execute the `.bat` file once a week at certain time at night, so reports are there in the morning.

Comment: Your suggetion works the same way as     rmarkdown::render("RexecKnit.Rmd") does. It works as a .R file, but not as a .Rexec file.

Comment: I'm not sure what the "C:\path_to_your_file\your_file.Rout" is for, but I'm giving it a go now.

Comment: I'm struggling with the Mini-Markdown formatting and the lack of luxury from the markdown preview functionality when we post new questions. I'll try and learn some more from the "Learn More" section as soon as possible so my comments don't look like total crap. I tried your suggestions. This opens the caller knit.R file in RStudio, and that's it. Details will follow when I'm up to speed on the use of mini-Markdown in comments.

Comment: Ok, make sure that the path to your R installation is correct. If paths are correct, it should work. If it does not, you can see the error message in .Rout file. This procedure works for me.

Comment: And one more thing, avoid naming your files with whitespace.

Comment: The path is correct. That much i know. I'll re-test the other details and get back to you. By the way, thank you for your quick answers!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91181/discussion-between-miha-trost-and-123apd).